# What's the usage of the speed control wheel in drills?

Tags: drill

What's the usage of the speed control wheel on the drills trigger button? What will I not be able to do without that red wheel? I am assuming if I press the trigger button, the drill will rotate slowly and if I press harder, it will rotate faster. Then what's the usage of that wheel?

[image]

Comment: The control wheel usually limits the speed - so you can pull the trigger all the way and still have the drill run at reduced speed. Less of a pain in the finger, that way.

Comment: @Paul Is that necessary for drilling holes? Or is it useful only when driving screws?

Comment: Sounds like an answer, @Paul! The larger the hole you're drilling and the harder the material, the slower you want to drill. Of course, large bits (> ~2" or so) start getting difficult to control in a hand-held drill and are often (but not always*) best left to the drill press (pillar drill in other parts of the world). *No, you can't take the joist to the drill press to make the 4" hole for plumbing, sadly...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Speed control on drills can be useful when you are drilling something very hard and are trying not to overheat a drill bit. Overheated drill bits can be ruined.

Or you are trying to drill a very large hole and you need to slow it down a bit to reduce the force acting on the drill and bit.

When using to drive screws, a slower rate can help prevent overdriving and cam out.

Some drills use a trigger pressure mechanism, but many use a dial and you adjust the speed by turning the dial.

Comment: On some, the dial adjusts the speed that will be held when the trigger is locked. That can be useful when you're using the drill as a motor for grinding and polishing accessories.